# Enterprise OS

Tags: opensuse, linux

Создал свой диструбутив Linux (`OpenSUSE`), но когда загружаюсь в `livecd` вместо нормального графического интерфейса `isolinux`, текстовый режим!Все настройки стоят! Раньше собирался без проблем, все было и грузилось с графикой а сейчас...

По пробовал из других сборок кинуть себе `isolinux`, все загрузилось с графикой!Но почему мой не грузится? Все `splash` и папки настроены и лежат в корне.

Могу выложить `live cd` ~650 `mb`.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите dmesg, логи